# Change the plot area colour for HighCharts Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts

setting the dynamic colour for plot area seems to be not working when I switched to dark mode in Swift iOS, tried below workarounds,

```
    let background = HIChart()
    background.backgroundColor = HIColor(rgba: 139, green: 188, blue: 33, alpha: 0.1)
    background.plotBackgroundColor = HIColor(rgba: 139, green: 188, blue: 33, alpha: 0.1)


    //Setting for view also
    chart: HIChartView!
    
    chart.chartBackgroundColor = UIColor(named: "BackgroundColor")
    chart.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "BackgroundColor")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to test this config:

```
let options = HIOptions()

    let chart = HIChart()
    chart.type = "column"
    chart.backgroundColor = HIColor(uiColor: .yellow)
    options.chart = chart

    let title = HITitle()
    title.text = "Demo chart"
    options.title = title

    let plotOptions = HIPlotOptions()
    plotOptions.series = HISeries()
    let animation = HIAnimationOptionsObject()
    animation.duration = 0
    plotOptions.series.animation = animation
    options.plotOptions = plotOptions

    let series = HIColumn()
    series.data = [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144, 176, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    options.series = [series]
```